# Problem with citing same author, different source

Tags: bibtex, ieeetran

I am using Jabref and  \IEEEtrans package. I try to cite same author for different source in the reference (twice). It appears twice but only once time appears Author name. I want like this

> [1] M. Shapiro, “Tire manufacturing,” 2012.
>
> [2] M. Shapiro, “Thermodynamic properties,” 2012.

Need help

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
%------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{datetime}
\newdate{date}{23}{09}{2016}
\date{\displaydate{date}}
\newcommand\HRule{\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}}
\usepackage{tabularx} % extra features for tabular environment
\usepackage{graphicx} % takes care of graphic including machinery
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry} % decreases margins
\usepackage{cite} % takes care of citations
%\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}

\begin{document}
this is \cite{Shapiro1,Shapiro2}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{LiteratureReveiw}

\end{document}


@TechReport{Shapiro1,
  author      = {Shapiro, M.},
  title       = {Development of the enthalpy storage materials, mixture of methyl stearate and methyl palmitate},
  institution = {Florida Solar Energy Center},
  year        = {1989},
}
@TechReport{Shapiro2,
  author      = {Shapiro, M.},
  title       = {Development of the enthalpy storage materials, mixture of capric acid and lauric acid with fire retardants},
  institution = {Florida Solar Energy Center},
  year        = {1989},
}
```

Comment: jabref is just a manager/front end for your bib files. It does *not* determine the formatting of the typeset bibliographic entries. Which bibliography style do you use?

Comment: I am using IEEEtran style

Comment: We will need a minimal example of your `.tex` and `.bib` input

Answer (score 3):

First, allow me define the problem properly. The problem is in `IEEEtran` bibliography, which the authors with same names are replaced with `-------`.
As an illustration, when I regenerated your code I saw this:
[image]

It is resulted of `IEEEtrans.bst` style. To overcome this, you should define 
 a `IEEEtranBSTCTL` entry in your bib database and change the default value for `CTLdash_repeated_names` like this:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@IEEEtranBSTCTL{IEEEexample:BSTcontrol,
CTLdash_repeated_names= "no",
}
\end{filecontents}
```

So we can do this in the main file with Macro as follows:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@IEEEtranBSTCTL{IEEEexample:BSTcontrol,
CTLdash_repeated_names= "no",
}

@TechReport{Shapiro1,
  author      = {Shapiro, M.},
  title       = {Development of the enthalpy storage materials, mixture of methyl stearate and methyl palmitate},
  institution = {Florida Solar Energy Center},
  year        = {1989},
}
@TechReport{Shapiro2,
  author      = {Shapiro, M.},
  title       = {Development of the enthalpy storage materials, mixture of capric acid and lauric acid with fire retardants},
  institution = {Florida Solar Energy Center},
  year        = {1989},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{IEEEtran}


\begin{document}

\bstctlcite{IEEEexample:BSTcontrol}

First one \cite{Shapiro1}. This is the second one \cite{Shapiro2}.


\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

And we active this change by `\bstctlcite{IEEEexample:BSTcontrol}` in our tex file main body. So the result would be as:
[image]

**A Nasty Trick:**
A nasty trick is to add a `\vspace{0mm}` in the name of the author, e.g. `\vspace{0mm}Shapiro`. Of course it not recommended at all.
I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is the normal output when you use `IEEEtran`: instead of repeating an author name, a dash is used.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@TechReport{Shapiro1,
  author      = {Shapiro, M.},
  title       = {Development of the enthalpy storage materials, mixture of methyl stearate and methyl palmitate},
  institution = {Florida Solar Energy Center},
  year        = {1989},
}
@TechReport{Shapiro2,
  author      = {Shapiro, M.},
  title       = {Development of the enthalpy storage materials, mixture of capric acid and lauric acid with fire retardants},
  institution = {Florida Solar Energy Center},
  year        = {1989},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\begin{document}
this is \cite{Shapiro1,Shapiro2}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't want the dash, use a different bibliography style. Or, more complicated, copy `IEEEtran.bst` in the working directory under the name `IEEEtran-mod.bst` and change line 128 from

```
FUNCTION {default.is.dash.repeated.names} { #1 }
```

to

```
FUNCTION {default.is.dash.repeated.names} { #0 }
```

Now use `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran-mod}` in your document and, upon running `pdflatex`, `bibtex` and `pdflatex` again, you'll get

[image]

Comment: This is an expected answer. But i am suffering. How to define in database what you mentioned above. In Jabref it automatically generate code. Then where can add this \RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@IEEEtranBSTCTL{IEEEexample:BSTcontrol,
CTLdash_repeated_names= "no",
}
\end{filecontents}

Comment: @ArulrajFigurado The `filecontents` environment is used just to make the example self-contained; you can use your `LiteratureReview.bib` file